# How to encode protocol property default implementation to dictionary

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, encodable

I want to make a dictionary from a encodable struct with a default implementation property.

```
struct MyStruct: MyStructProtocol {
    var value: String
}
```

The struct implements a protocol. That protocol has two variables. One variable has a default implementation.

```
protocol MyStructProtocol: Encodable {
    var defaultValue: String { get }
    var value: String { set get }
}

extension MyStructProtocol {
    var defaultValue: String { return "my-default-value" }
}
```

To that I use that `Encodable` Extension from [How can I use Swift’s Codable to encode into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209743/how-can-i-use-swift-s-codable-to-encode-into-a-dictionary):

```
extension Encodable {
    var asDictionary: [String: Any]? {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
    }
}
```

So when I instantiate the struct and "encode" it to a dictionary:

```
let myStruct = MyStruct(value: "my-value")
let myStructDictionary = myStruct.asDictionary
```

then the `defaultValue` is not included:

```
["value": "my-value"]
```

**But what I need is** (included the defaultValue):

```
["defaultValue": "my-default-value", "value": "my-value"]
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because protocol `Extensions must not contain stored properties`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synthesized encoder considers only the members in the struct, not any properties in a protocol extension nor computed properties.

You have to write a custom initializer. And I'd prefer to make the struct adopt `Encodable` rather than the protocol.

```
struct MyStruct: MyStructProtocol, Encodable {
    var value: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case value, defaultValue }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
        try container.encode(defaultValue, forKey: .defaultValue)
    }
}

protocol MyStructProtocol { ...
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`Encodable` will not recognise computed properties. To fix that, override `encode(to:)` function as shown in the official documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

EDIT: A possible solution to the problem:
[How to use computed property in a codable struct (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309815/how-to-use-computed-property-in-a-codable-struct-swift)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the default value for `defaultValue` has been implemented in extension for the protocol, which means that it is a *computed property*.

```
struct MyStruct: MyStructProtocol {
    var value: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
        case defaultValue = "my-default-value"
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
        try container.encode(defaultValue, forKey: .defaultValue)
    }
}
```